# How to show uploaded image on upload_success page - codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload, refresh

I have an upload page in my codeigniter app and when i upload an image and click submit it redirects to a page called 'upload_success' i want to show the image you just uploaded on that page.

How can i do that?

I used

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function reload(){window.location.reload();} 
</script>
```

but then it uploads the image two times.

NOTE: i am using Ci's file uploader class.

Comment: Are you using CI's file uploader class?

Comment: yes I do. I will add that to my question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See CI's [File Uploading Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).

If going by their controller example, on success this code is executed:

```
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
$this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
```

The image information is in the $data passed to the view, so in the upload_success view, you need to set something like:

```
<img src="http://mysite.com/path/to/uploads/<?php echo $upload_data['file_name']; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `upload_success` also the page that does the upload? because if it is then that is bad architecture because every time user refreshes that page the image will be uploaded again and again.

What you need to do is, on form submit call a script like `image_upload` which only does the upload then redirects to `upload_success` which shows message `(success/failure)` and in that page add an `<img>` tag which has its `src` set to the previously uploaded image.

Comment: No i have a page upload_form and when i submit it runs the do_upload function in my controller and after that it redirects to upload_success page where it show's me the file data i just uploaded.